# How to use prepare() with dynamic column names?

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, prepared-statement

I have a function that takes an sql table column name string as a parameter, returns 1 string result:

```
function myFunction($column_name) {
    return $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT %s FROM myTable WHERE user_id=%s", $column_name, $current_user->user_login));
}
```

However, this code does NOT work, since with the nature of prepare, I can't use a variable for column names (and table names).

This works, but I think it poses a security issue:

```
return $wpdb->get_var('SELECT ' . $column_name . ' FROM myTable WHERE user_id=' . $current_user->user_login);
```

What do I need to do in order to to use dynamic column names in my prepare statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a list of "approved" values instead, that way you're not really using user data inside a query.  Something like this:

```
$Approved = array ('firstname', 'lastname', 'birthdate') ;
$Location = array_search($ColumnName, $Approved) // Returns approved column location as int
if($Location !== FALSE) {
    // Use the value from Approved using $Location as a key
    $Query = $wpdb->Prepare('SELECT ' . $Approved[$Location] . ' FROM myTable WHERE user_id=:userid');
    $Query->Execute(array(
        :userid => $current_user->user_login
    ));

    return $Query;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Maybe it might be easier to just get all (SELECT * or SELECT a,b,c,d) of the user data and save it to session to use later?

Comment: This works. However, how "secure" is $Approved[$Location] inside the prepare() from being tampered with? Thanks!

Comment: @Rollor  The code does not use any truly dynamic values, only the values in the $Approved array.  As long as you do not allow any way to change that array it will be secure.  It's basically validating $ColumnName against a list of approved values that you set manually.  If i does not validate then it won't run the query.  Values sent in the Execute are protected against injection, so there is no need to validate/clean those.

Comment: ...and since $ColumnName has no choice but "to go through" $Approved, I think it makes sense.

Comment: Would `sanitize_text_field()` do enough to keep the data safe rather than whitelisting?

Comment: WordPress 6.2 now supports `%i` placeholders for table and column names. You can see my answer below.

Comment: `$Location` is not relevant beyond `false` (you don't need the key of the matched value) so just use `in_array()`.

Answer (score 3):

## As of Mar 29, 2023:

As of [milestone 6.2](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/milestone/6.2), which was released Mar 29, you can now use `%i` instead of `%s` as a placeholder inside `$wpdb-prepare()` statements for table and column names. Here is a [dev-note](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2022/10/08/escaping-table-and-field-names-with-wpdbprepare-in-wordpress-6-1/) about it with examples.